# Why is the Rigify rig coming in wrong?

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]When I generate the rigify rig it seems to make everything flat instead of 3D.
The outside ring with the arrows should be at the feet or origin.
How do I fix this problem.
Thanks [image]

Comment: Have you applied the rotation, location, and scale to the metarig and the mesh before the generation of the rig?

Comment: yeah all transforms